# Selecting one option out of many - Objective c

Tags: cocoa-touch, user-interface, selection

Hi I am looking for a component wherein an option can be selected out of many options given. The component allows the user to select only one option, the moment any option is selected the previously selected one gets unselected. When I look in the xcode I couldn't find any component similar to it. I have attached the image of the component here which am looking for. Can anyone point me to this component (refer image attached) in xcode. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a grouped `UITableView`. You need to implement the logic to maintain the selection yourself in the table view delegate.

Comment: So can this be done using a simple uitableview with options populated in it ?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an `UITableView` to me. Probably easiest to use with a `UITableViewController`

Answer (score 0):

On your UITableView go to your Attributes Inspector and there is an option in the third section down labeled 'Selection'.  There's your place!

[image]